# cmake: how to check runtime of a library?

Tags: c++, cmake

How to check the version of runtime for a library which I located with find_package()? I mean, how can I figure out flags that were used to build given library - /MT or /MD (on Win) ?
**Edit**: how to check that flags in general, not necessarily by cmake?

Answer (score 1):

With a tool that lists the DLLs that your binary is linked against, you can find out whether it was linked with /MD or not.

Say you have Cygwin and can run `objdump -x c:\path\to\file.exe` and use grep to see whether it includes a file such as "MSVCP100D.dll":

```
if objdump -x c:\path\to\file.exe | grep MSVCP100D.dll
then
    # compiled with /MD
else
    # compiled with /MT
fi
```

There are other tools to check for libraries if you cannot use Cygwin, but the principal will be the same. The grepping could be done within cmake too.